# Trying to install Magento, get error msgs about PHP version & extensions

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I've downloaded and installed XAMPP.

Now I'm trying to install Magento on my Windows10 laptop. 
The problem is, Magento Installer is giving me this error, 
[image]
So I downloaded and extracted PHP 7.0.6. But I don't know how to install it. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
Another problem is about the extension as shown in the picture below, 
[image]
How to solve these problems, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Open your xampp control

Step 2 : Click config open php.ini or (install xampp location xampp\php\php.ini)

Step 3 : rename ;extension=php_xsl.dll to extension=php_xsl.dll

Step 4 : rename ;extension=php_intl.dll to extension=php_intl.dll

Comment: Thank you but rename them to the same name? and how to install php 7.0.6?

Comment: Download xampp installer file from here >> [Download xampp ](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)  . Create a folder xampp-7 and install it here.